# Check Bitcoin address balance from blockchain

Tags: java

I am a merchant that accepts bitcoins, and I'm building my own desktop client for receiving them in Java.

When I receive a transaction, I would like to be able to see in my client how much bitcoin is stored in the address that I am receiving from.

I have the full blockchain downloaded on my computer.

How can I access the balance of an address from the blockchain? I would like to be able to do this offline by accessing the blockchain stored on my hard drive.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can look at the source code of full-mode bitcoin implementations in Java, such as [bitsofproof (BOF)](https://github.com/bitsofproof/supernode).

It seems [bitcoinj](http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/) also has a [full-mode](http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/wiki/FullVerification) but it is experimental only and not really suitable for prod.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Using the `bitcoinj` Java library, you can retrieve your current balance very easily:

```
// To create your wallet.
public static NetworkParameters params = TestNet3Params.get();
public static String filePrefix = "forwarding-service-testnet";
public static WalletAppKit kit = new WalletAppKit(params, new File("."), filePrefix);

// to retrieve your balance.
String balance = kit.wallet().getBalance().toFriendlyString();
System.out.println(balance);
```

Comment: Your example code uses the Bitcoin testnet, while the OP wants to know how to check the balance from his locally-downloaded blockchain. Can you update your answer accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this blockchain link to get the balance

https://blockchain.info/q/getreceivedbyaddress/THEIRBITCOINADDRESS?confirmations=6

while you request it from the java